Calculating expectation and variance for a random variable sampling from two independent Poisson distributions
I got this question in an interview and could not solve it.
Question setup
Given two independent Poisson random variables $X_i\sim Pois(\lambda_i)$, for $i=1,2$. Additionally, $Y$ is a random variable with Bernoulli distribution, i.e. $P(Y=1)=P(Y=2)=\frac{1}{2}$ and lastly a fourth random variable $X$ that sample from both Poisson random variables with equal probability, i.e.
$$
X = \begin{cases} 
X_1 & \text{when } Y=1, \\
X_2 & \text{when } Y=2.
\end{cases}
$$
So essentially, assign one of the Poisson random variables to a face of a coin and flip it.
Find $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and Var($X$).
Solution attempt
Starting with the expectation, I utilized the law of total expectation:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[X] &= \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=1]P(Y=1) + \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=2]P(Y=2) \\
                  &= \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) .
\end{align*}
$$
Next, I utilize the law of total variance,
$$
    \text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(X \mid Y)] + \text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]) .
$$
Evaluating the two terms of the right-hand side separately, starting with the first term and using law of total expectation again,
$$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(X \mid Y)] &= \text{Var}(X \mid Y=1)P(Y=1) + \text{Var}(X \mid Y=2)P(Y=2)\\
         &= \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) .
\end{align*}
$$
Now for the second term,
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]) &= \mathbb{E}\bigl[(\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - E[X])^2 \bigr] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2 - 2\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[X]^2 \bigr]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2] - 2\mathbb{E}[X]^2 + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X]^2]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2] - \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2) + \frac{1}{4}(\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2)\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2] - \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2).
\end{align*}\\
$$
For the last part, how do I solve the term $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2]$? Is it even the correct approach?
Thanks in advance!

I don't see the definition of $Y$!

@geetha290krm my bad, added!

I believe you are able to compute variance from $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)=\lambda_1 I(Y=1) + \lambda_2 I(Y=2)$.

Note that $\Bbb{E}[X]^2 = \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2 \neq \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2)$.

You got mixed up due to several little mistakes along the derivation; let's recall a few things. Firstly, let's highlight that a conditioned random variable $X|Y$ is nothing else than a "layered" random variable, in the sense that the variable $X$ depends on a second variable $Y$. In the present case, one has :
$$
X = f(Y) = 
\begin{cases}
   X_1 & \text{if } Y = 1 \\
   X_2 & \text{if } Y = 2
\end{cases}
$$
This layering allows to take "partial" or "total" averages, depending on the considered layers, at the risk of getting lost in muddy notations nonetheless, that is why we have to be cautious at each step.
Even if you have computed the expectation correctly with the help of the law of total expectation already, let's redo it in order to fix the notation and see how to process. Actually, the random variables are averaged in two steps, because of the two layers, i.e. $\Bbb{E}[X] = \Bbb{E}[\Bbb{E}_Y[X|Y]]$, with
$$
\Bbb{E}_Y[X|Y] = \sum_k f(Y=k)\Bbb{P}(Y=k) = \frac{1}{2}(X_1+X_2),
$$
hence $\Bbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}(\Bbb{E}[X_1]+\Bbb{E}[X_2]) = \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ in the end.
Now, the variance of $X$ is given by $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \Bbb{E}[(X-\Bbb{E}[X])^2] = \Bbb{E}[X^2] - \Bbb{E}[X]^2$ by König's relation $-$ it is to be noted that the law of total variance is nothing else than a restatement of König's identity by rearranging the summations between the two layers $-$, where the first term is treated as above, i.e. $\Bbb{E}[X^2] = \Bbb{E}[\Bbb{E}_Y[X^2|Y]]$, with
$$
\Bbb{E}_Y[X^2|Y] = \sum_k f(Y=k)^2\Bbb{P}(Y=k) = \frac{1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2),
$$
hence $\Bbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{2}(\Bbb{E}[X_1^2] + \Bbb{E}[X_2^2]) = \frac{1}{2}\left((\lambda_1+\lambda_1^2) + (\lambda_2 + \lambda_2^2)\right)$ and finally
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{2}\left((\lambda_1+\lambda_1^2) + (\lambda_2 + \lambda_2^2)\right) - \frac{1}{4}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2 = \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2} + \left(\frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}\right)^2.
$$

thanks for such a detail explanation!

@user1383042  You're welcome ;)

Given that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ takes value $\lambda_1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and takes value $\lambda_2$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, this is how we can compute its variance:
\begin{eqnarray*}\text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X|Y]) & = & \frac{1}{2}\left(\lambda_1-\left(\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}\right)\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\lambda_2-\left(\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}\right)\right)^2 \\ &=& \left(\frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}\right)^2\end{eqnarray*}

It's probably simpler to use
$$\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2$$
and calculate $\mathbb E[X^2]$ conditioning on $Y$ in the same way that you did for $\mathbb E[X]$. No confusing yourself about what "conditional variance" is.

this was indeed much simpler. Thank you

$\qquad\begin{align}Y&\sim\mathcal{U}\{1,2\}\\X\mid Y&\sim\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda_Y)\\[2ex]\mathsf E(X) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\lambda_Y)\\[1ex]&= \lambda_1\mathsf P(Y=1)+\lambda_2\mathsf P(Y=2)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}\\[2ex]\mathsf {Var}(X) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(X\mid Y))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\lambda_Y)+\mathsf{Var}(\lambda_Y)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}+\dfrac{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2}{2}-\dfrac{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2}{4}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}+\dfrac{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2}{4}\\[3ex]\blacksquare\end{align}$
